# Using Torsocks on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, mac, perl, tor

I used Torsock and usewithtor fine when I had MAC OS X 10.6, and didn't use it for a while. I upgraded to Mountain Lion a few months ago, and I tried to use it but no luck on it. 
Output is following:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library: /opt/local/lib/torsocks/libtorsocks.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I'm not sure why it complained about dyld which locates at right location.
It also produced perl-dynamic error log:

```
Process:         perl-dynamic [13084]
Path:            /usr/local/ActivePerl-5.10/bin/perl-dynamic
Identifier:      perl-dynamic

Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [13531]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-01-31 03:14:15.638 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          429027 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           38
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   4

Anonymous UUID:                      1EF6A147-F21F-6CA7-6BA2-E9A910B314C1

Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  could not load inserted library: /opt/local/lib/torsocks/libtorsocks.dylib

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x1ffc +perl (???) /usr/local/ActivePerl-5.10/bin/perl
0x8fe66000 - 0x8fe98e57  dyld (210.2.3) <23DBDBB1-1D21-342C-AC2A-0E55F27E6A1F> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBookPro5,5, BootROM MBP55.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.26 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.47f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3030352E4130324C4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3030352E4130324C4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.81.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: FUJITSU MJA2160BH FFS G1, 160.04 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS23N
USB Device: iPhone, apple_vendor_id, 0x12a0, 0x24100000 / 3
USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0x24400000 / 2
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0x26500000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06100000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8213, 0x06110000 / 4
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0236, 0x04600000 / 3
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0x04500000 / 2
```

I tried to find similar case on google, but also no luck. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I just installed "torsocks" on my Macbook Pro running 10.8.4 using MacPorts.

Possibly, try removing the version you have and reinstall.

1. [Download MacPorts here](http://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. Open your Terminal: `sudo port install torsocks`